# c++ write to a file, but file is empty

Tags: c++, file, io, decimal, converters

I have this code for turning decimal into binary and write it to a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int d,num,s,r,k,sum=0;;

void main()
    {
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("binary.txt",ios::in);
        cin >> d;
        while(d>0)
        {
            r=d%2;
            sum=sum + (k*r);
            d=d/2;
            k=k*10;     
            myfile << sum;
        }  
        cout << "Encryption Succesfull"<<endl;
        myfile.close();
    }
```

The program runs successfully, but the file is empty.

The file name is right, no syntax errors, etc.

What to do?

Comment: Are you getting into your `while` loop at all?

Comment: Compile with moderate optimization (i.e., for GCC at least `-O`) and *all* default warnings at least (i.e., `-Wall`). It should tell you you are using variables without asigning them values (at least `k` in my superficial scan of the code).

Answer (score 4):

You use the wrong flags for opening the file:

```
myfile.open("binary.txt",ios::in);
```

It should be

```
myfile.open("binary.txt",ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myfile.open("binary.txt",ios::in);
```

opens the file for reading. If you want to **output** something, use `ios::out` or leave the param empty (since the default value is `ios_base::out` anyhow):

```
myFile.open("binary.txt");
```

I've found this line on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/), but it **doesn't seem to be true** (tested on devC++ 4.9.9.2, uses some MinGW version):

> out is always set for ofstream objects (even if explicitly not set in argument mode).

Removing the second parameter or changing it to `ios::out` does fix the problem.

Comment: And you can open it through the constructor.